# Tuple object not callable

Tags: sqlite

I have created a sqllite connection and try to call a table using query but getting below error.

I am getting error:

> tuple object not callable

while writing query in sqllite3 in python.

```py
import sqlite3
con=sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite)
pd.read_sql_query("""select * from reviews""",con)
```

Comment: Please post the code with proper formatting, it looks like you're missing a single quote after sqlite in the connect() call.

Answer (score 0):

Try catching the results of read_sql_query like so:

```
import sqlite3
con=sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
df = pd.read_sql_query("""select * from reviews""",con)
```

df now contains your DataFrame.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html